# Open URL in new tab instead of new window in FPM application

Tags: abap, webdynpro, sap-r3

I'm building an application in FPM and I'm trying to open an external URL in a new tab. I'm using the following code:

```
data: lr_fpm                       type ref to if_fpm,
      lr_nav                       type ref to if_fpm_navigate_to,
      ls_url                       type fpm_s_launch_url,
      ls_nav_additional_parameters type apb_lpd_s_portal_parameters.

if lr_fpm is not bound.
  lr_fpm = cl_fpm_factory=>get_instance( ).
endif.
lr_nav = lr_fpm->get_navigate_to( ).
ls_url-url = '<A URL leading to a different application within my organisation>'.
ls_nav_additional_parameters-navigation_mode = 'EXTERNAL'.
call method lr_nav->launch_url
   exporting
     is_additional_parameters = ls_nav_additional_parameters
     is_url_fields            = ls_url_oi.
```

Unfortunately, in all browsers this opens a new window instead of a new tab. Is there some parameter that changes this behavior to opening the external URL in a new tab?

Thank you in advance,

Joshua

Answer (score 0):

you can add the attribute target="_blank" to the end of your url.
Maybe if you add this to the "IS_ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS" it will work as well.

Unfortunately, I currently do not have access to my SAP system to test this.
But it is worth a try